# Referencing Autofilter Results in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am currently experimenting using VBA and autofilter to query a dataset (as per [Populate Excel Data Validation Drop-Down From Data Range Condition Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193080/populate-excel-data-validation-drop-down-from-data-range-condition-using-vba) )

However I am having trouble using VBA to refer to the auto filter results.

How can I collect results without needing to copy and paste? (for example to store a result as a variable)

How can I check how many results have been found, and trigger a msg box when the auto filter produces no results?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's very hard to help without seeing what code you have tried and where it's failing. A lot of people could write code for you if they were willing, but even if they did, who knows if it would *actually* suit your needs and it could potentially raise more questions. Help us help you by showing your efforts. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the special parameters xlCellTypeVisible and SpecialCells.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim SheetERP As Worksheet
    Set SheetERP = Worksheets("MyDatas") 'Sheet with data

    Dim myTabela As Excel.ListObject
    Set myTabela = SheetERP.ListObjects("CodeData") 'Named Table range

    Dim qtd As Integer 'To count filtered data rows (only visible)
    qtd = SheetERP.ListObjects("CodeData").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    'OR
    qtd = myTabela.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

    MsgBox qtd

    Dim TFiltro As Range
    Set TFiltro = SheetERP.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'OR
    Set TFiltro = myTabela.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'Do what you want with TFiltro

End Sub
```